# Assets not routing properly with NGNIX, Node 8.11 and Angular 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, nginx

I have an issue getting assets to load properly in our current setup. We use NGINX, Node 8.11, angular 6

In a nut shell, I had to do some parsing of request coming into our node server.js to get files to load properly for angular.

Here is the setup a typical application called heroes:

**Nginx**

```
location /heroes/ {
    proxy_pass 
    http://unix:///myapps/tmp/node.sock;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge";
}
```

**Node Server.js**

```
...

//==============================================================
// Point static path to dist
//=================================================================
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/')); 
// set the static files location for the angular build
...
```

**Node Server.js - create an allowed extension list**

```
...

// Allowed extensions list can be extended depending on your own needs
const allowedExt = [
    '.js',
    '.ico',
    '.css',
    '.png',
    '.jpg',
    '.woff2',
    '.woff',
    '.ttf',
    '.svg',
    '.map',
    '.otf',
    '.eot',
    '.gif'
];
...
```

**Node Server.js - route files to the angular dist**

```
...    
// Redirect all the other requests
// TODO: This part is a hack. 
//The main issue is express not serving up the static assets
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  if (allowedExt.filter(ext => req.url.indexOf(ext) > 0).length > 0) {
       var iFileStart=req.url.lastIndexOf("/");
       var sFile=req.url.substring(iFileStart+1);
       res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/'+sFile));
    } else {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/index.html'));
    }
  });
```

...

**Angular index.html**

```
...    
<base href="/heroes/">
...
```

With this setup - my apps work for the most part. I had to add a few more kludges into it for some other issues.

The problem is - express or my nginx setup wasn't routing the request for assets correctly before this hack. I'm pretty sure I shouldn't have to check file extensions and route them differently.

If I change the Node Server.js file to this:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
             res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/index.html'));

  });
```

Then I get this error in the browers:
[JS files being served as html?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM96h.png)

It seems that the files can be found but aren't being processed as JS files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figure out my own issue.

Had to edit the following:

NGINX:

```
location /heroes/ {
    root /app/mydir/heroes/dist <--- added this
    proxy_pass http://unix:///myapps/tmp/node.sock;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge";
}
```

Server.js

```
...
//======================================================================
// Point static path to dist - false will cause a 404 if not found
//========================================================================
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    next();
  }, express.static(__dirname+'/dist',{fallthrough:true})); 
...

....
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/heores/index.html'));

  });
...
```

angular.json

```
 "outputPath": "dist/heroes",
```

Now everything works. Hopefully others will find this useful.